# Cannot override default Bootstrap style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have `nav-tabs` element for the menu. In the bottom of the `nav-tabs` is sort of a border which is default in Bootstrap. I tried to change the color or even delete it but none of these is working.

I tried to override tthe property in the Bootstrap which in the source code looks like this:

```
.nav-tabs { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
```

Maybe this is not the correct selector of that `border`, so this could also be a problem.

Here is the fiddle of project: http://jsfiddle.net/eenho5dw/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this selector:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eenho5dw/3/

Comment: this is the correct answer, +1 for you. It would be better if you explained why. And whoever voted you down, it would be amazing to read the explanation

Answer (score 1):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/eenho5dw/6/

You need to target the correct elements:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
.nav-tabs { border-bottom: 1px     solid #ddd !important; }
```

Even if it doesn't work, try adding internal style if possible (recommended, if have to apply css to one or few pages).

Answer (score -1):

Please use this style

```
  .nav-tabs {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;
   }
```